# What is the name of this tree with yellow flowers?

Tags: botany, species-identification, trees

Location is South India,

Tree is very large, but leaves are very small.
[image]
Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsSKp.jpg

Comment: For next time (because it has already been answered), it would be good to have a close-up on the flowers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peltophorum_pterocarpum 
Peltophorum pterocarpum or the Copperpod

[image]
[image: Copperpod]

Comment: How did you find it? which site helped you to identify this tree?

Comment: Honestly? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trees_of_India This right here.

Comment: @MalharKhushu OP's specimen almost certainly *Peltophorum pterocarpum* ; but the picture you attached, looks slightly different, with drooping inflorescence, and leaflets are quite different.

Comment: Sorry, @AlwaysConfused should I find a new picture?

Comment: @MalharKhushu that might be better. You would find more typical image on [wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Starr_030514-0025_Peltophorum_pterocarpum.jpg) and [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Peltophorum_pterocarpum) such as [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Peltophorum_pterocarpum#/media/File:Hoa_va_la_muong_la_lac.jpg) and [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Peltophorum_pterocarpum#/media/File:Fruit_Pods_I_IMG_3317.jpg) . If you have trouble with image resize, feel free to let me know; I'll made smaller version for you.

Comment: I don't know the image attached currently to your answer is really a different species or just another form-variation of *P. pterocarpum*; but it is looking much atypical than *P. pterocarpum*.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused is this better?

Comment: @MalharKhushu Seems better